# Get Binary data using XMLHttpRequest without redirecting page

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load a binary array using XMLHttpRequest. It downloads fine (The console.log is printed), but then Chrome immediately tries to redirect the page to the file itself, which is not very helpful...

```
let data;

var location = '/static/data/dinar.r4';

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", location, true);

oReq.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
    if (arrayBuffer) {
        console.log(`Successfully loaded data ${location}`);
//        data = new Float32Array(arrayBuffer);
    }else{
        throw new Error(`Could not load ${location}`);
    }
};

oReq.send(null);
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I just came to the conclusion that my issue has nothing to do with the XMLHttpRequest, and rather is because of the presence of the line

```
var location = ...
```

This sets the window location, rather than creating a new variable called location...